# Question about vector spaces involving polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the set $V$ of real polynomials $f$ of degree at most
3 which satisfy $f(1) = f(2)$. Define addition and scalar multiplication
of such polynomials by $(f +g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ and $(αf)(x) = α·f(x).$

Show that the following polynomials $f_1(x) = 1$, $f_2(x) = x^2 − 3x$ and $f_3(x) = x^3 − 7x$ form a basis of $V$, and is the polynomial $g(x) = 3 + x + 2x^2 − x^3$
in $V$ ?

If yes, what
are the coordinates of g with respect to the basis in above?
What is the dimension of V ?

Progress:
I am thinking of finding the RREF of the matrix associated with the 3 polynomials, and if it gives the identity matrix, then it is a basis. To check if g is in $V$, should I be writing $g(x)=\alpha f_1 + \beta f_2 + \gamma f_3$ then solve for the scalars? But how do I find the coordinates of $g$ with respect to the basis above and also the dimension of V?
Is $dim_v$= $4$?

Can anyone confirm my method in doing this question? Thanks!

Comment: Don't let the notation trip you up. As a vector space you replace $x^n$ with $x_n$ and ignore that they're polynomials entirely. In my rough work I would write $f_2(x)$ as $(0,-3,1,0)$ to correspond with the polynomial $0 -3x +x^2  +0x^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the defining properties of a basis: all the proposed basis vectors are orthogonal to each other, i.e. are not scalar multiples, and there are the same number of them as there is dimension to the space.

By observation, the three functions you've been given are all orthogonal - they each have distinct powers of $x$ so it's impossible to scale any of them to form any of the others. You have three of them, but it's not obvious that $V$ is only three dimensional.

To demonstrate that $V$ is actually three dimensional rather than four, you can interpret the constraint as defining one of the four coefficients in terms of the other three (freely variable) ones, meaning you only have three choices. Specifically, we can imagine expanding out $f(x)=\alpha x^3 + \beta x^2 + \gamma x + \delta$:

$$\alpha 1^3+\beta 1^2+\delta 1+\gamma = \alpha 2^3+\beta 2^2+\delta 2+\gamma$$
$$\alpha +\beta + \delta + \gamma = 8\alpha +4\beta +2\delta +\gamma$$
$$\delta = -7\alpha -3\beta $$

(The choice of solving for $\delta$ was arbitrary, I just chose that because I expected the result to be neater; $\gamma$ disappearing entirely isn't a problem, it just means it is both unconstrained by and has no influence on the value of the other three)

The "coordinates of g with respect to the basis" means, what scalars do we have to multiply the polynomials $f$ by so that the sum of them is $g$? Constructing $g = Af_1 + Bf_2 + Cf_2 $ and solving for the coefficients should produce the right answer and immediately means e.g. $A=3$